# Regex to replace repeated characters

Tags: java, regex

Can someone give me a Java regex to replace the following.

If I have a word like this "Cooooool", I need to convert this to "Coool" with 3 o's. So that I can distinguish it with the normal word "cool".

Another ex: "happyyyyyy" should be "happyyy"

```
replaceAll("(.)\\1+","$1"))
```

I tried this but it removes all the repeating characters leaving only one.

Comment: Have you tried using `$1` three times?

Comment: It works for "coooool". But when used for "happyyyyyy", it gives "happpyyy".

Comment: try adding another `\\1` to your pattern

Comment: It works!! thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change your regex like below.

```
string.replaceAll("((.)\\2{2})\\2+","$1");
```

- `(` start of the first caturing group.
- `(.)` captures any character. For this case, you may use `[a-z]`
- `\\2` refers the second capturing group. `\\2{2}` which must be repeated exactly two times.
- `)` End of first capturing group. So this would capture the first three repeating characters.
- `\\2+` repeats the second group one or more times.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sX9vW1/5)

Comment: @stribizhev ya, op catures the dot , so I did the same.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might want something like this:

```
str.replaceAll("([a-zA-Z])\\1\\1+", "$1$1$1");
```

This will match where a character is repeated 3 or more times and will replace it with the same character, three times.

`$1` only matches one character, because you're surrounding the character to match.
`\\1\\1+` matches the character only, if it occurs at least three times in a row.

This call is also a lot more readable, than having a huge regex and only using one `$1`.